# EGID and RGID incorrectly displayed in ps o/p?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this:

```
$ ls -l test1.sh 
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root root 24 2011-05-31 13:27 test1.sh # sgid root

$ id
uid=1001(abc) gid=1001(abc) groups=4(adm),6(disk),20(dialout),21(fax),24(cdrom),26(tape),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),104(  fuse),106(lpadmin),112(netdev),121(admin),122(sambashare),1001(abc),1002(sbox)
```

But, when I run test1.sh, I do not see the Effective Group Owner to be root in ps o/p.. why ?

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,cmd,euid,euser,ruid,ruser,egid,egroup,rgid,rgroup,nice,tty,user

  PID  PPID CMD                          EUID EUSER     RUID RUSER     EGID EGROUP    RGID RGROUP    NI TT       USER
 8793  2349 bash                         1001 abc     1001 abc     1001 abc     1001 abc      0 pts/2    abc
 8865  8793 /bin/bash ./test1.sh         1001 abc     1001 abc     1001 abc     1001 abc      0 pts/2    abc
 8866  8865 sleep 60                     1001 abc     1001 abc     1001 abc     1001 abc      0 pts/2    abc
 8868  8793 ps -o pid,ppid,cmd,euid,eus  1001 abc     1001 abc     1001 abc     1001 abc      0 pts/2    abc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing safe shell scripts is *really* hard. Think about `$PATH`, `$IFS`, ... So, Linux doesn't honour the setuid/setgid bit for shell scripts.

Comment: "Linux doesn't honour the setuid/setgid bit for shell scripts." Is this blanket statement always true ? I am running Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @abc: Yes, look at the man page for execve() on your system. You'll see "Linux ignores the SUID and SGID bits on scripts."

Comment: Under NOTES: man execve " Linux ignores the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits on scripts."

Comment: Correct; the bits are only ignored for executables which start with #!/path/to/interpreter

Answer (score 2):

The ps output gives you a clue.  The thing you're running is bash with your script as an argument.  Since bash isn't suid, it can't elevate permissions.

Linux - and most unixes - don't allow suid shell scripts either way.  It's implemented as part of the exec() system call that they ignore suid/sgid on anything being interpreted through the #! mechanism (see `man execve`).  To work around this, you'll most likely want to use sudo and potentially call it from within your shell script (which is somewhat safer anyway).

To run part of the script using sudo, you would use the -u or -g options to sudo to launch your script.  So, you'd make a rule in /etc/sudoers (which is beyond the scope of this answer) allowing you to run the script.  Say your script is /tmp/script, and you're abc.  to run the command as the user "sauer" without being prompted for your password, you'd add this to /etc/sudoers:

```
abc ALL = (sauer) NOPASSWD: /tmp/script
```

and run this command

```
sudo -u sauer /tmp/script
```

To run it as a member of the admin group, you'd add this line:

```
abc ALL = (%admin) NOPASSWD: /tmp/script
```

and run this command

```
sudo -g admin /tmp/script
```

Read the sudoers man page and surf around Google to find more documentation on sudo.  You combine users and groups with commas in that parenthetical expression (ie, `(sauer,root,%admin)`)

Comment: @danny Thanks ! But I changed /bin/bash to be sgid. But the o/p did not change from what I have described above.

Comment: @danny I did not understand what you mean in your second answer paragraph. Can you give an example ?

Comment: First - as a security professional, I'm horrified at the thought of changing permissions on bash to include sgid. :)  But anyway... Try running /bin/bash /path/to/script instead of just running the script directly and see if that changes the behavior.  I *think* the "ignore setid" logic is in exec and triggered by the #! mechanism, so you might find that runnning sgid bash directly changes the behavior.

Comment: For the second paragraph, are you referring to "explain what exec() does" or "how would I use sudo for this"?

Comment: $ sudo chmod 2755 /bin/bash
$ /bin/bash ./test1.sh & . This did not change anything. Sorry to horrify you :)

Comment: @dannysauer: I would expect `bash script.sh` to drop privileges as well, unless you pass it the `-p` switch.

Comment: @ninja: yeah, the shell should also be smart enough to drop privs; the -p option isn't documented in my bash man page, except that it's mentioned that -p doesn't reset the effective UID.  So I'm thking the sgid behavior must also be handled through exec, before the shell has a chance to see a different EGID v/s GID.